# Magento2 Add css class to admin ui grid column

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, css, uicomponent

I need to add some css rules to one of the columns of my custom admin ui grid. Is there a way to add css class to it from listing xml file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just add "fieldClass" property to the column configuration:

```
<column name="column_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">your-css-rule(s)</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: How about if you want a dynamic class based on the value or just the value of the column?

Comment: working perfect Thanks @V Korotun

Answer (score 2):

```
<column name="your_column">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Your Column</label>
        <fieldClass>
            <class name="your_css_class">true</class>
        </fieldClass>
    </settings>
</column>
```