# Magento 2: How do I hide a column from an admin grid?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

Using 2.1.3, is there a way to **hide an entire column from a UI component admin grid**? I found [Magento2 Add css class to admin ui grid column](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120979/magento2-add-css-class-to-admin-ui-grid-column), and that hides the column, but not the column header (misaligning the grid columns).

Comment: From your response below it sounds like you're trying to show/hide an order grid column based on the currently logged in admin user. Did you ever find a solution for that?

Answer (score 8):

use `<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>`
in the config node of data argument when declaring column

eg.

```
<column name="created_at">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created at</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

*the only issue that the filter won't showing until you switch the column back to visible*

Comment: Thanks @Mammouth, but this looks like a config setting - I want to be able to change the visibility based on the users role, so it would have to check it in code.

Comment: acl wasn't created for this  ... but for mimic something similar just extend/override `Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/column.js` with your business logic

Comment: otehrwise  I think would be good to open a new thread to your current problem (hiding column by user role settings), because this one already solved

Comment: @Mammouth, But the filter should visible, only can we hide from column?

Answer (score 5):

You can try with `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

For example:

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`

```
<field name="backorders">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks @Khoa, but I want to display the column depending on the user's permissions, so I want the column there, but to start hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your ui xml to remove columns

```
<column name="name_of_column">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           </item>
      </argument>
</column>
<field name="name_of_column">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           </item>
      </argument>
</field>
```